# How to get a subprocess check_output to call a script with sys.argv?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to get a sys.argv to be passed along with a script name in a subprocess that calls another script and returns the output.  I am receiving a couple different errors trying to execute the program.  One is **TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int**.  I get this one with the code listed below.

When I try to convert the mytext to a string, str(15) I get this error:  **Command '('python /users/cmbp/p4e/helloworld_final2.py', '15')' returned non-zero exit status 1.**

When I just try to run the subprocess calling the second script (helloworld_final2.py) with no sys.argv, it works fine.

Also, the helloworld_final2.py file runs fine when I call it from the command line with a sys.argv.  For example python /users/cmbp/p4e/helloworld_final2.py 15 will return the number 15 in the print statements.  This does not work from the script subprocess_test.py.

Here is the script (subprocess_test.py) with the subprocess:

```
import subprocess

mytext = 15
cmd = "python /users/cmbp/p4e/helloworld_final.py", mytext
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

Here is the script that I am trying to call (helloworld_final2.py):

```
import sys

def cooz():
    print (sys.argv[1])
    print ('hello world!')

def tooz():
    print ("here is another line")

print ("stuff")
tooz()
cooz()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `cmd` by formatting it as a list.

```
cmd = ["python",  "/users/cmbp/p4e/helloworld_final.py", str(mytext)]
```

Then

```
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

Shall work.